# "Mark item as read when selection changes" not working properly in Outlook 2017

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

After a recent update, the option "Mark item as read when selection changes" is not working properly in Outlook 2017.

The item is marked as read but only for a second or two and then it becomes unread again. I have to go on it second time before it stays read.

It was working perfectly fine before the update. I couldn't find anything about this on the web. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Wanted to show the messages as read when selection changes. I tried:

> File -> Options -> Advanced -> Reading Pane -> Mark item as read when selection changes.

But this did not work. So, I opened up the reading pan at the bottom of outlook(It was not there before). And Selected the other option:

> Mark item as read when viewed in the reading Pane

and I put 0(zero) in the Wait box.
Now, when I select an email, it opens up in the bottom reading pane and shows as read.

Answer (score 0):

What’s the detailed version of Outlook? check this via File > Office Account > About Outlook.

When marking read in Outlook client, please check if status also changed on the web mail. 
If not, the status may sync to Outlook client from server and then the email become unread again.

Please repair Outlook data file to test the results: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253

If issue continues, please create a new profile.

Comment: Version 1903. I have tried repairing the Outlook data files, that did not help. I will now try and create a new profile.

Comment: Does it work in a new profile?

Comment: When you new profile, do you mean removing the email account and re-adding it?

Comment: You can check this article: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-outlook-profile-f544c1ba-3352-4b3b-be0b-8d42a540459d